# Filtering TCP connections with short duration in Wireshark

Tags: wireshark

How can I filter packets for TCP connections with short duration (e.g. 3 seconds)?

I guess there may be something like

```
ip.addr == xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx && (time(tcp.flags.fin==1) - time(tcp.flags.syn==1)) < 3sec
```

blahblah, but I cannot make the corrent filter string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to `Statistics -> Conversations`, then chose `TCP` tab and sort conversations by their duration by clicking on `Duration`. Now you can prepare each conversation or apply it as a filter and follow its stream. Also, you can copy the list using the `Copy` button.

This way doesn't filter all of the connections altogether by one click, but if there aren't too many connections, you can prepare a filter for each connection and then display them (right-click on each conversation, `Prepare a Filter -> ...or Selected` .